# How to use Attributes of a directive in ng-model of a html tag designed in the template using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When I am trying to understand how to pull attributes and placing them in a directive, I found the following fiddler...

Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/f3JL3/)

Adding one more question for the above...If I want to display the below

```html
<div ng-model="foo">foo</div>
```

How should I modify the above code. Will it work ????

```html
<div ng-model="{{tooltipTitle}}">{{tooltipTitle}}</div>
```

Comment: {{ }} (Double braces) is a directive by himself.. Just like ng-model

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have value as a ng-model

ng-model should always be a name which is binded to the scope of the controller.

your ng-model should be like

```
<div ng-model="tooltipTitleModel">{{tooltipTitle}}</div>
```

but as you are using it on a div it will not have any affect to your code because ng-model in actual works with **input, textarea or select** elements

for more details on naming and usage of ng-model please see the link below:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Hope this resolves your question.

Comment: I have taken "div" rather an input for just an example. But I need to have an input element where I have to add "ng-model" dynamically to it as below. 

<div><input type="text" ng-model="foo"/></div>

Comment: could you please share more code so as to understand your exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the variable to which your input element is bound through `ng-modal`, you need to get it done indirectly through a `watch` inside the controller. You watch your modal variable for the changes and divert the value according to the state.

```
<input ng-modal="marks">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('marks', function(val){
    $scope.classReport[$scope.student] = val;
});
```

In the above example, the `marks` you input will be going to the correct student in the `classReport` array depending on the value of the `$scope.$student`.

You don't have to bind your input element directly and dynamically to each array element as you have tried in your own example.